# Sending HTTP answer without waiting for my queries to complete - Cloud Functions - Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

I wrote a cloud function which is triggered by a link and I am having a problem with that. The answer is been sending before all the instructions were completed, I tried to use a Promise but I had no success.

My code:

```
    exports.controlaPtsMensal = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var dia_atual = new Date();
    var usuariosRef = admin.database().ref('users');
    usuariosRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var user = snapshot.val();
            var cont = 0;
            for(var i in user){
                cont = cont + 1;
                var data_pontos = user[i].data_controle_pts;
                var data = new Date(data_pontos);
                var timeDiff = Math.abs(dia_atual.getTime() - data.getTime());
                var diferenca = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) - 1;
                admin.auth().getUser(i)
                  .then(function(userRecord) {
                    console.log("Email do usuário: ",userRecord.email);
                    if(userRecord.email == "test@hotmail.com"){//diferenca == 30 && 
                        send({
                            //to: [userRecord.email],
                            to: [test@gmail.com'],
                            subject: 'Último dia para usar seus pontos!',
                            html: '<b>Mensagem de App Anjo ' + '<br></b><br><br><b>Mensagem: </b><br>Hoje é o último dia para você'
                            + ' resgatar ou doar seus pontos, vamos lá ! :)'
                        });
                    }
                  })    
            }
          res.status(200).send('Função de controle de pontos executada com sucesso!');
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to collect all the promises from all the calls to `admin.auth().getUser(i).then(...)` into an array, then pass that array to [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in order to wait for all of the work to complete *before* sending the final response.

This is a very common pattern, and it should be easy to find examples that are similar to what you're doing.  For example, [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/message-translation).

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it and my problem was solved!